# SharePoint 2010 intranet site user profile search issue

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a sharepoint 2010 classic intranet site with a search box at top. When i search for a user than it takes me to the search page but when i click on the name of the user then it gives the error page. On checking the logs, i get below error -

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access Denied: You may only
>   retrieve your own profile's privacy setting, unless you are an
>   administrator.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileValueCollectionBase._GetPrivacy(Boolean
>   checkPermissions)     at
>   Accenture.Posten.Mylink.Common.ScoreCard.UserProfileEvaluator.EvaluateUserProfile(UserProfile
>   userProfile)  61dd1ba8-c46d-4962-8a2c-b92692649bdc 04/04/2018
>   10:15:32.06   w3wp.exe (0x0A74)                           0x237C  Unknown
>     Posten                          0000    Medium 
>     UserProfileEvaluator.EvaluateUserProfile: Failed to read field
>   'AboutMe' 61dd1ba8-c46d-4962-8a2c-b92692649bdc 04/04/2018 10:15:32.06
>     w3wp.exe (0x0A74)                           0x237C  Unknown
>     Posten                          0000    Medium 
>     System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access Denied: You may only
>   retrieve your own profile's privacy setting, unless you are an
>   administrator.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileValueCollectionBase._GetPrivacy(Boolean
>   checkPermissions)     at
>   Accenture.Posten.Mylink.Common.ScoreCard.UserProfileEvaluator.EvaluateUserProfile(UserProfile
>   userProfile)  61dd1ba8-c46d-4962-8a2c-b92692649bdc 04/04/2018
>   10:15:32.06   w3wp.exe (0x0A74)                           0x237C  Unknown
>     Posten                          0000    Medium 
>     UserProfileEvaluator.EvaluateUserProfile: Failed to read field
>   'PictureURL'  61dd1ba8-c46d-4962-8a2c-b92692649bdc 04/04/2018
>   10:15:32.06   w3wp.exe (0x0A74)                           0x237C  Unknown
>     Posten                          0000    Medium 
>     System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access Denied: You may only
>   retrieve your own profile's privacy setting, unless you are an
>   administrator.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileValueCollectionBase._GetPrivacy(Boolean
>   checkPermissions)     at
>   Accenture.Posten.Mylink.Common.ScoreCard.UserProfileEvaluator.EvaluateUserProfile(UserProfile
>   userProfile)  61dd1ba8-c46d-4962-8a2c-b92692649bdc 04/04/2018
>   10:15:32.06   w3wp.exe (0x0A74)                           0x237C  Unknown
>     Posten                          0000    Medium 
>     UserProfileEvaluator.EvaluateUserProfile: Failed to read field
>   'SPS-Responsibility'  61dd1ba8-c46d-4962-8a2c-b92692649bdc 04/04/2018
>   10:15:32.06   w3wp.exe (0x0A74)                           0x237C  Unknown
>     Posten                          0000    Medium 
>     System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access Denied: You may only
>   retrieve your own profile's privacy setting, unless you are an
>   administrator.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileValueCollectionBase._GetPrivacy(Boolean
>   checkPermissions)     at
>   Accenture.Posten.Mylink.Common.ScoreCard.UserProfileEvaluator.EvaluateUserProfile(UserProfile
>   userProfile)  61dd1ba8-c46d-4962-8a2c-b92692649bdc 04/04/2018
>   10:15:32.06   w3wp.exe (0x0A74)                           0x237C  Unknown
>     Posten                          0000    Medium

Can someone help on this??

Comment: after clicking on the user name does site URL changed to mysite or it remains on the same site?

Comment: Is user profile service application working on you farm? may be it is permissions issue , app pool that running intranet require manage  profile permissions refer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/1f8aa3f2-9f5a-4a9f-9ea6-d423b131398c/access-denied-to-create-a-user-profile-you-must-be-an-administrator-or-create-your-own-profile-and?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010, user can use privacy categories to specify that only certain people can view some of the details in his profile, his site and distribution list memberships, and his list of colleagues.

Privacy Settings:

- **Only Me** to limit visibility to the user only.
- **My Manager** to limit visibility to the user and the user’s manager only.
- **My Team** to limit visibility to the user and the user’s immediate team.
- **My Colleagues** to limit visibility to the user and all the users who are listed in the user’s My Colleagues list.
- **Everyone** to share information with every user who has viewer or higher permissions to a site.

Based on the error message, it seems that you don’t have access to his user profile.

More information:

[Configure policy settings on user profile properties and personal and social features (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262930%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Manage the information you share through your My Site and profile](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-the-information-you-share-through-your-my-site-and-profile-630c65ab-e17f-4d50-b7a5-8e1892ff711b)